# json_utils.dumps is suddenly returning all unicode from flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo, bson

I have a flask application running on centos 6.5 that today suddenly starting spitting out mongodb documents as all unicode from a flask response. it appears `json_utils.dumps` appears to be the culprit.

```
results = database.db.collection.find({}).sort('dateCreated', DESCENDING)

resp = Response(json_util.dumps(results),
                mimetype='application/json')
return resp
```

my response object comes back with a just a bunch of unicode. I edited my code just to see if it was something with the query, mongodb, or pymongo and this works fine printing to stdout

```
results = database.db.collection.find({}).sort('dateCreated', DESCENDING)
for r in results:
    current_app.logger.info(r)
```

However this

```
results = database.db.collection.find({}).sort('dateCreated', DESCENDING)
for r in results:
    current_app.logger.info(json_utils.dumps(r))
```

its back to printing out unicode to stdout

Can anyone help me figure out what has gone wrong with my server and why json_utils might start doing this? I'm not experiencign this on my dev machine hooked up to the same database running the same exact code. I don't recall any updates I've made to this server either. its been running fine until this morning

Comment: What do you mean by "just a bunch of Unicode"? Are you talking about `u'hello world'`? Or are you talking about a series of characters that are rendering incorrectly?

Comment: for example I was getting this {"\uda00\udc74\udac0\udc74e\u0000\ud900\udc64": "\ud840\udc31\udb80\udc33\ud840\udc31\udb80\udc33\udbc0\...

I may have found the issue though. This may be an incompatibility with my python wheel on the machine I'm deploying to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with my python wheel that I used on this machine. The wheel I used was built against a machine running a different version of centos and a different kernel version. I loaded up a machine with the correct versions of both that matched my deployment machine, redeployed the wheel and reinstalled the libraries and the issue was resolved.